# How to PDF file open in browser without download in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, pdf, xamarin.forms, privacy-policy

Currently am using Label using span text to separate privacy policy and terms and conditions. In Terms and conditions worked as expected because they provided an HTML URL but the Privacy policy Url in the pdf link. Is that possible to click the option to show the browser or drive to view the pdf in xamarin forms?

Comment: Yes.  Add a gesture recognizer to the label and use [Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=android) to open the url, or you can use a `WebBrowser` control if you want to keep the user in your app.  But not every Android device is capable of displaying PDF

Comment: Currently am using Browser.OpenAsync not working as expected.  can u pls provide any sample in WebBrowser @Jason

Comment: "not working as expected" does not tell me anything useful.

Comment: @Jason, when we click on the Privacy policy, link the in mobile application it shows blank screen but same time downloads pdf with privacy policy with right content.